# Spotify SPTAuthViewController issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, authentication, spotify

I am having trouble authorizing Spotify. The first time I believe I logged in but it froze up on the last page of the authentication process. Now when I try to log in, the popover is a blank screen. Also when I clear my cookies, the login screen appears but won't proceed past me entering my username and password. I appreciate the help here

I have tried doing this in both objective c as per the "Simple Track Playback" demo in the sdk and in swift using this tutorial http://pachulski.me/2015/spotifyframework-with-swift/

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue (blank popover). This was fixed when I added "App Transport Security Settings" (type: Dictionary) into the info.plist, and then implementing "Allow Arbitrary Loads" (Type: BOOL) and setting it to "YES".

Please refer to the screenshot:
[image]

EDIT: Added code to answer Brian's question in comments:

```
- (IBAction)loginButtonPressed:(id)sender {

_authVC = [SPTAuthViewController authenticationViewController];

_authVC.delegate = self;
_authVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
_authVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
[self presentViewController:_authVC animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Would you mind letting me know your process implementing the API?

Comment: I followed the source you linked (Which helped me a lot, I wasn't aware of the SPTAuthViewController popover until I ran into this post). It shouldn't be very different from what you coded. Added my IBAction code to the answer (When the user taps my "login" button). It's in Obj-C, but I hope that's alright.